# Cake PHP - problem with auth component

Tags: php, cakephp

My problem is that a variabile is not past from the controller to the view when the user is not logged in, but it is viewable when the user is logged in. My controller method looks like this:

```
function publicprofile( $username ) {
        $user = $this->Users->find('first', array('conditions' => array('username' => $username)));
        $this->set('user', $user['Users']);
    }
```

The method is in the allowed list and everything works, just that $user is not set.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `debug($user)`?

Comment: Yes, everything seems ok in the controller, but the variable isn't defined in the view

Comment: Why are you saying it's a problem with the AuthComponent? Does it work if you remove Auth? I've experienced something similar recently where a variable just wouldn't `set` with `set(compact('varname'))`, but would work with `set('varname', $varname)`. Maybe you have the reverse...?

Comment: I'm unclear on "The method is in the allowed list and everything works, just that $user is not set."  Can you debug( $user ) inside of your controller, i.e., to verify that you're retrieving the user info?  If you change the view variable name (as suggested below, to myUser) does it work?  Can you set other variables inside that method and have them output in the view?

Comment: I was saying it is a Auth component problem because everything was working just fine when i was logged in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AuthComponent must be overwriting your $user variable in the view. Rename it in your controller like so:

```
$this->set('myUser', $user['Users']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->set('user', $user['Users']);
```

should be **singular**

```
$this->set('user', $user['User']);
```